# Unable to skip ranking Post when there is no ranking information in CakePHP2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

It's hard to explain it with words, but what I want to do is skip the ranking when there is no ranking information in CakePhp2. For example, I have the following data that contains 7 rows of ranking data. 2 out of the 7 row contains the empty body(2nd and the 5th row). So I made a script to skip the ranking post that is empty. However, Since the 2nd and the 5th rows that have been skipped. The data post that is displayed is 1,3,4,6,7. But I want to the display the ranking like 1,2,3,4,5. In other words, I want to show the 3rd ranking as 2nd and 4th as 3rd and so forth. Sorry for my poor explanation. Simply, I want to skip ranking when there is no ranking information and show the ranking number. (PS: I don't want to alter the DB) I will love to hear from you!

```
   array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(6) "title1" ["body"]=> string(5) "body1" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-04 21:25:43" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [1]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-04 21:25:43" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [2]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["title"]=> string(6) "title3" ["body"]=> string(5) "body3" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-04 21:25:43" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [3]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["title"]=> string(6) "title4" ["body"]=> string(5) "body4" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-08 15:48:21" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [4]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-08 16:14:08" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [5]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["title"]=> string(6) "title6" ["body"]=> string(5) "body6" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-08 16:14:08" ["modified"]=> NULL } } [6]=> array(1) { ["Post"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["title"]=> string(6) "title7" ["body"]=> string(5) "body7" ["created"]=> string(19) "2017-04-08 16:14:08" ["modified"]=> NULL } } }
```

Trying to make a script to show the Popular ranking. I really love to hear about some great Hints and samples from you!

```
 <h1>Popular Ranking posts</h1>
        <?php $k = 1; ?>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i <= count($posts); $i++) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php if (!empty($posts[$i]['Post']['body'])) { ?>
            <h2><?php echo $posts[$i]['Post']['title']; ?></h2>
            <li>
                <?php 
               echo $posts[$i]['Post']['body'];
                ?>
            </li>
//Want to show the number 2 in $k even though the 2nd body data is missing(Currently 3rd data).
            <h3 class="ranking_number"><?php echo $k;  ?></h3>
            <?php } else { 
         continue;
            }?>
        </ul>
        <?php $k++; } ?>
```

Comment: Just move `$k` inside the `if`? That would show 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, so you will also have to declare `$k` with 0 as value instead of 1

Comment: My explanation might be confusing but For example, there would be 7 data (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), but since 2 and 5 are skipped, it would be (1,3,4,6,7) but I want to show it like (1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: I know. If you move `$k` increment inside the `if`, it will show 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <h1>Popular Ranking posts</h1>
        <?php $k = 1; ?>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i <= count($posts); $i++) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php if (!empty($posts[$i]['Post']['body'])) { ?>
            <h2><?php echo $posts[$i]['Post']['title']; ?></h2>
            <li>
                <?php 
               echo $posts[$i]['Post']['body'];
                ?>
            </li>
//Want to show the number 2 in $k even though the 2nd body data is missing(Currently 3rd data).
            <h3 class="ranking_number"><?php echo $k;  ?></h3>
            <?php $k++; } ?>
            <?php } else { 
         continue;
            }?>
        </ul>
```

## What was changed?

I moved `$k++;` inside of `if`, just before `else`

## Why?

### What was your code doing:

- Set `$k` to 1.
- Post 1 isn't empty, so show it (rank 1).
- Increase `$k` by 1.
- Go to next post
- Post 2 is empty, so don't show it (rank 2).
- **Increase `$k` by 1.**

Let's stop there. Your `$k` was increased with every post, even those skipped, so the third position was 3rd instead of 2nd.

### What is my code doing:

- Set `$k` to 1.
- Post 1 isn't empty, so show it (rank 1).
- Increase `$k` by 1.
- Go to next post
- Post 2 is empty, so don't show it (rank 2).
- Go to next post
- Post 3 isn't empty, so show it (**still rank 2**).

I hope I helped.